# I want to show database result in PHP but it keeps giving the same error

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
<?php 
require_once('../mysql_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT customerName
                FROM customerName
                WHERE membership = 0";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);


echo '<table width="75%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
<tr>
<td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>CUSTOMER NAME
</div></b></td>
<td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>APPROVE
</div></b></td>
<td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>REJECT
</div></b></td>
</tr>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

echo "<tr>
<td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\">{$row['customerName']}
</div></td>

<td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\"> /*this is supposed to show a button*/
</div></td>
<td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\"> /*this is supposed to show a button*/
</div></td>

</tr>";


}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I want to show the content of my database in PHP
so I used a code used from another program!

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

(this statement is supposed to mean while the db /row has content?)

```
 $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$displayName);
```

whenever I use it for my program it gives me the same error over and over, error is that:

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

I give it `mysqli_result`
 but it says I gave a boolean!
 I try to enclose mysqli_result in '' just because the former errors were like it's expecting 'mysqli_result' but it becomes a string so I tried changing `mysqli_fetch_array` into `mysqli_fetch_row` which shows the same error!!
 also would it be because I am wanting to show buttons in the table?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to you.

> db.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','crud_db');

    if(!$conn){
        die('error connecting to database');
    }
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php


    require_once('db.php');

        $query = "SELECT *
                    FROM employees";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);


    echo '<table width="75%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" 
    cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>EMPLOYEE NAME
    </div></b></td>
    <td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>APPROVE
    </div></b></td>
    <td width="10%"><div align="center"><b>REJECT
    </div></b></td>
    </tr>';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo "<tr>
    <td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\">{$row['ename']}
    </div></td>

    <td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\"> <button type=\"button\">Approve</button>
    </div></td>
    <td width=\"10%\"><div align=\"center\"> <button type=\"button\">Reject</button>
    </div></td>

    </tr>";


    }
    echo '</table>';

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I've had it working already I realized my 'FROM' part of the query is wrong because it's seeking a column and not a table. On the other hand thank you :)